# pasting commands into macvim does not interpret as commands

Tags: vim

I find that from Mac's system clipboard pasting a command into `macvim`, such as `:set history?`, it does not get interpreted as command in normal mode, rather, it is pasted into the buffer as text.

This is different behavior from my `vim`. My `macvim` info is

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Oct 30 2019 23:05:43)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-2234
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

Comment: You can remap it: `nnoremap <D-v> @+` in your vimrc should be enough. (Maybe you'll also want `xnoremap <D-v> @+` as well for visual mode.) I can write an answer if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @filbranden that does not work. either one.

Comment: Does `@+` work to interpret the contents of the clipboard as command in normal mode? It should... (If that part works, thn the problem is with the mapping instead.)

Comment: @filbranden how can i know/test? the superkey `D` I assume is the same as `cmd` in macvim on my mac?

Comment: Yes, the `<D-` modifier is for command-key on Macs. (See `:help <D-`.) Does the `@+` command work for you? `@` executes the contents of a register in normal mode (see `:help @`) and `+` is the register for your external clipboard... Do you see the existing mapping when you query it with `:nmap <D-v>`? Are you in nocompatible mode? (Run `:set cp?` to query and `:set nocp` to set it.)

Comment: @filbranden yes, I check the mapping is there and I am in nocompatible mode. However, when I paste `:h` from system clipboard with `cmd+v`, I am still seeing it pastes into the text, not as a command. thanks.

Comment: If you have `:h` in your clipboard and you type the normal command `@+` do you get it to execute `:h` as a normal command and start typing the `:h` command, or even execute it if you had a "return" at the end? I'm trying to understand whether the `@+` part is working for you or not...

Comment: @filbranden yes, when I have `:h` in my clipboard and I type the normal command `@+` I get it to the command.

Comment: Alright, so it seems we only need to install the mapping then... If you're inside Vim already and you install the mapping with `:nnoremap <D-v> @+`, do you then get to execute the command in normal mode pasting with Command-V? What does `:nmap <D-v>` show you (before and after)? If you add that to your vimrc, does it not work as expected?

Comment: @filbranden i know this is super weird. I did `:nnoremap <D-v> @+`. And then with my system clipboard has `:h`, I did `cmd-v`, I am still seeing the text into the window not on the command prompt. `:nmap <D-v>` shows me `n  <D-v>       * @+<CR> `

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is different has to do with the programs performing the paste.  When you paste into MacVim, as a GUI program, it is aware of the paste command and pastes directly into the buffer, which is consistent with how almost all other Mac editor (and word processor) programs behave.

When you paste into a terminal Vim, you're pasting into the terminal itself, not Vim.  As a consequence, the terminal just sends those characters on to the program (Vim) as if you'd typed them yourself.  Vim, in this case, has no knowledge of where those characters came from and doesn't distinguish typed characters from pasted characters.

If you want to paste a command in command line mode, you can type `q:` to bring up a command line buffer.  You can then paste and edit that command as you wish using normal Vim commands, pressing Enter to apply it.

Comment: Even just starting command mode with `:` then pasting should work (I don't have MacVim at the moment, so this is from memory).

Comment: yes, either `q:` or `:` can do. I knew it. But I wanted to change the behavior to be in normal mode, paste command, in insert mode, paste into the text. Is there any way to achieve this behavior, as in normal `vim`?

Comment: That said, bracketed paste can affect this some (and help you avoid security issues from such copy-paste)